# I can't export my BGE game as .app

Tags: game-engine, export, add-on, osx

I have created a game in BGE and I am trying to export it as an .app.

I went into *Add-Ons* and activated *Save Game As Game Engine Runtime*. When I go to File > Export > Save As Game Engine Runtime, it says

> The player could not be found! Runtime not saved

When I go to run it as a *Standalone Player*, it says

> Player path: '/private/var/folders/j1/n61my9px6cgc695j5_kpwfcc0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/87947515-F243-4122-8A6D-377D08161CE7/d/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/MacOS/MacOS/MacOS/blenderplayer.app/Contents/MacOS/blenderplayer' not found

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender. I have tried going to the folder above and it should have a file called *blenderplayer* in it but it does not.

How can I fix this issue?

I'm on Mac by the way.

Comment: What build are you suing? Where did you download it from? Not all builds include Blenderplayer

Comment: I'm using 2.78c and I downloaded it from blender.org. It includes the app Blenderplayer in the folder where the Blender app is.

Comment: I think that "save as game engine runtime" exports as .exe for windows but not really sure.

Comment: Yes it does, but it also exports .app for MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you *copy* blenderplayer.app over to that empty folder. Then, you could use it. There is also likely a preferences input for the player path. I once copied blenderplayer.app from one computer to another through Google drive, I think it worked (it was a while ago). I am currently not with my computer, but good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't think I'm having the problem anymore, I made this post like 3 years ago. But thanks anyway for trying to help!

Comment: Oh! I just realized it was 3 years ago. I was on my phone, and it was in My Tags Unanswered, but I am happy to help!